# Create a form that takes user's input and adds it to a sentence when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to replicate something like this [the page takes the user input like name and displays the name in a sentence on the next page](https://www.lemonade.com/start/1)

I have programmed a similar code but it doesn't match what I need. Any help or tutorial on this would be appreciated.

full code added. I want to be able to have my name on the seconde prompt like 'Greg type an adjective'. but i'm finding it difficult.

```js
// List of prompts for the user
var prompts = [
 'Type your name',
 'Type an adjective',
 'Type a noun'
   ];

var answers=[];
// Keep track of current prompt we're on
var currentPrompt = 0;

// A function that will call the next prompt
var nextPrompt = function() {
  //if there's no answer in the form
  if (currentPrompt != 0){
    answers.push($('input').val());
  }
 // if there is a next prompt
 if (currentPrompt < prompts.length) {
  // put first prompt in all html elements with class 
  $('.prompt').html(prompts[currentPrompt] + '<br><input type="text">');
  // move the next prompt into variable currentPrompt 
   
     currentPrompt = currentPrompt + 1;
 }

  


 //or else if we're at the end of the array
 else {
  // put a new message into the html.
  showFinal();
 
 }
}

//puts user answers into HTML
var showFinal = function() {
  $('.prompt').html('This is the story of <span class="fill">'+answers[0]+'</span> and the <span class="fill">'+answers[1]+'</span> <span class="fill">'+answers[2]+'</span>.');
  //and then hide the button
   $('button').hide();
}
// run nextPrompt function when button is clicked
$('button').click(function() {
 nextPrompt();
});

// Show the first prompt as soon as js loads
nextPrompt();
```

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One';
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #e6eaf0;
  }
  
button{
  margin: 40px;
  }
  
input {
  font-size: 24px;
  }
  
.fill {
  background: white;
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  font-family: 'Shadows Into Light';
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 4px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="prompt"></div>
<button>Next</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How do you take input afore the page has loaded?
In addition, if that's all of your JS it's conspicuous it won't work. Maybe provide us adscititiously with the required HTML you have and the full JavaScript.
P.S. Your code demands jQuery you know?

Comment: It does have jquery i will paste the full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm... Interesting.

I managed to get the code in the snippet below work as you specified. I added `{name}` to the second prompt. When that prompt is called, the user has already entered their name on the previous one => `answers[0]` is set and is the user's name. Therefore, I placed an `if` in `nextPrompt()` to check whether the current prompt is the second one. And if it is, then I am replacing `{name}` from `prompts[1]` with `answers[0]`. Quite stupid, but I hope you find it useful.

```js
// List of prompts for the user
var prompts = [
 'Type your name',
 '{name}, type an adjective',
 'Type a noun'
   ];

var answers=[];
// Keep track of current prompt we're on
var currentPrompt = 0;

// A function that will call the next prompt
var nextPrompt = function() {
  //if there's no answer in the form
  if (currentPrompt != 0) {
    answers.push($('input').val());
  }    
 // if there is a next prompt
 if (currentPrompt < prompts.length) {
  // put first prompt in all html elements with class
    if (currentPrompt == 1) {
      prompts[1] = prompts[1].replace("{name}", answers[0]);
    }
  $('.prompt').html(prompts[currentPrompt] + '<br><input type="text">');
  // move the next prompt into variable currentPrompt 
   
     currentPrompt = currentPrompt + 1;
 }

  


 //or else if we're at the end of the array
 else {
  // put a new message into the html.
  showFinal();
 
 }
}

//puts user answers into HTML
var showFinal = function() {
  $('.prompt').html('This is the story of <span class="fill">' + answers[0] + '</span> and the <span class="fill">' + answers[1] + '</span> <span class="fill">' + answers[2] + '</span>.');
  //and then hide the button
   $('button').hide();
}
// run nextPrompt function when button is clicked
$('button').click(function() {
 nextPrompt();
});

// Show the first prompt as soon as js loads
nextPrompt();
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One';
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #e6eaf0;
}
  
button {
    margin: 40px;
}
  
input {
    font-size: 24px;
}
  
.fill {
    background: white;
    color: red;
    border-bottom: 2px black solid;
    font-family: 'Shadows Into Light';
    padding: 0 6px;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="prompt"></div>
    <button>Next</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just purely to replicate the user's name, why not use sessionStorage?

On the prompt page:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('name', name.value);
sessionStorage.setItem('adjective', adjective.value);
sessionStorage.setItem('noun', noun.value);
```

On the page displaying the data:

```
$('.prompt').html('This is the story of <span class="fill">'+sessionStorage.getItem('name')+'</span>
```

Comment: Why using the local storage, while the prompts are all on the same page and the document remains loaded with all the variables? The problem is that the prompts' text is already defined afore the user types in their name, so you can't have `answers[0]` in the `prompts` array.

Comment: OP described copying the functionality of the linked example which passed values onto another page

Answer (score 0):

Use a POST method form on your first page. Its default behaviour is to send the form data to the second page as a URL search parameter. You can query the search parameter in the second page:

Page 1:

```
<form action="secondpage.html" method="POST"> 
<input type="text" name="name" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

Page 2:

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = window.location.search;
```